# GWT: Response not coming back to Form onSubmitCompleteEvent when a servlet sends a file in response to browser

Tags: gwt, download, httpresponse

Code on client side :

```
@UiHandler("form")
void onFormSubmission(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
    hideProcessingPopUp();
    if (event.getResults().contains("Exception")) {
        // handle exception
    }
}
```

Servlet code in doPost method:

```
response.setContentType("text/csv");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="
            + exportType + ".csv");

    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            response.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));

    // Adding content
    List<CustomObject> list = (List<CustomObject>) anonymousList;
    for (CustomObject eachObject : list) {
        writer.append(eachObject.getContent());
        writer.newLine();
    }

    writer.flush();

    // Gently close streams/writers.
    close(writer);

    return fileContent;
```

Servlet code is fine, as am getting expected data and file. Problem is with response not reaching the client side i.e., SubmitCompleteEvent. Please help me out, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is how browsers work; and [the javadoc for `FormPanel`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.html#FormPanel%28%29) actually warns you about it:

> The back-end server is expected to respond with a content-type of 'text/html', meaning that the text returned will be treated as HTML. If any other content-type is specified by the server, then the result HTML sent in the onFormSubmit event will be unpredictable across browsers, and the `onSubmitComplete` event may not fire at all.